# How are "The app is currently unreachable" error pages served?

Tags: web-applications, google-chrome, offline

I've noticed while using Google Chrome that if a website such as Facebook, YouTube or Google Docs is inaccessible a certain error page that says "**The app is currently unreachable.**" is served, like the one below.

[image]

Is this internal to Chrome or is it part of an offline web app manifest file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Chrome detects that the user is going to a site defined by an *installed application* and it is unreachable it will display this page.

If the user doesn't have an app installed that uses one of the urls defined in the manifest that you are trying to reach you will see a normal descriptive error about connectivity issues.

Answer (score 0):

Because chrome always use secure connection for web store, its apps and if your time is different the there must be have problem.On the other hand Kinal is also right. This type of error is seen many times in chrome webstore.

Answer (score -1):

I usually experience this from my slow home connection. So, I concluded that Google Apps is not reachable from slow connections. If you are experiencing this with slow connection, try it with faster one(if available)

The same error message will be displayed if your Internet is disconnected while you are signed into your gmail and try to continue with an already signed in gmail account.